# How to use autoconf with C++0x features

Tags: c++, c++11, autoconf

What are the best practices for using `autoconf` in conjunction
with `shared_ptr` and other TR1/BOOST C++0x templates so as to maximize
portability and maintainability?

With `autoconf` I can determine whether `shared_ptr` is
available as `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and/or `boost::shared_ptr`.  Given 
that the same feature has two different names, I have the following
questions:

1. In the code, how should `shared_ptr` be referenced?
2. Should `std::tr1::shared_ptr` be preferred over `boost::shared_ptr`?

For the first, the code is currently using preprocessor conditionals 
allowing non-qualified references to `shared_ptr`, a la

```
#if HAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
#elif HAVE_BOOST_SHARED_PTR
using boost::shared_ptr;
#else
#error "No definition for shared_ptr found"
#endif
```

Second, the code uses `std::tr1::` over `boost::` to minimize
dependencies on external libraries (even if the the libraries are
widely used).

Are these two solutions common?  Are there better ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One improvement to your example code, and an answer to your first question, is to use the "[template typedef](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm)" idiom:

```
#if HAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR
    template <class T>
    struct SharedPtr {
        typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> Type;
    };
#elif HAVE_BOOST_SHARED_PTR
    template <class T>
    struct SharedPtr {
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> Type;
    };
#else
#   error "No definition for shared_ptr found"
#endif

// Declare a shared_ptr using our wrapper classes, saving us from having to care
// where shared_ptr comes from:
SharedPtr<int>::Type my_shared_int(new int(42));
```

The main problem with this is the need to use the ::Type notation.  It is purely because C++ currently has no way to have a typedef for a template.  You can have a typedef for a template type *instance*, but it's important here that we retain genericity.

As for whether you should prefer TR1 to Boost, I'd say yes.  Now that compilers are shipping with partial C++0x support, I'd say you should also test for std::shared_ptr and prefer that to either of the others.

You might need a fourth typedef if there are compilers that have a shared_ptr that's somewhere else.  I don't know of such a compiler, but some C++ code I maintain does something similar to what you're asking about with the common `slist` extension to the Standard C++ Library, for singly-linked lists.  Old g++ versions put it at global namespace, modern g++ puts it in the compiler-specific `__gnu_cxx` namespace, and we even found one that erroneously put it in `std`!

Comment: I don't see what your template typedef adds beyond the original poster's suggestion.  He's "polluted" things with shared_ptr<T>.  You've polluted things with SharedPtr<T>::Type.  Both seem equivalent, and his involves less typing.

What does your template typedef accomplish beyond the using statement in the original post?

Comment: You hit on it: you no longer need to hoist these names out into the global namespace. My method doesn't necessarily add global names; you can namespace it if you like. And if you don't, mine is far less likely to conflict with names in another library.

Comment: Given that shared_ptr will eventually be in std:: and that autoconf can determine in which namespace shared_ptr is defined, I'm leaning towards "namespace std { using <somewhere>::shared_ptr;}" if there is no std::shared_ptr defined.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: how about `template<class T> using SharedPtr<T> = std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>`? There is no need to define a type function if the selection is made by the preprocessor. And you can namespace any declaration, be it a `typedef` or a `struct`.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: That's [new C++11 syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), added to solve this very problem. This question was asked before C++11 came out. Even today, a whole lot of programmers are going to still be using C++ compilers without even TR1 support, much less complete C++11 support. (Me included.)